# How to fix Slick Exception of single AutoInc column returned on INSERT

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, slick-3.0

I tried to implement the akka-http rest example provided at
https://github.com/ArchDev/akka-http-rest
 but I'm stuck with the

```
    slick.SlickException: This DBMS allows only a single column to be returned from an INSERT, and that column must be an AutoInc column.
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcStatementBuilderComponent$JdbcCompiledInsert.buildReturnColumns(JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala:67)
```

Here is the Scala Code:
Signup API:

```
path("signUp") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      post {
        entity(as[UsernamePasswordEmail]) { userEntity =>
          complete(Created -> signUp(userEntity.username, userEntity.email, userEntity.password))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

AuthService.scala

```
def signUp(login: String, email: String, password: String): Future[AuthToken] =
    authDataStorage
      .saveAuthData(AuthData(UUID.randomUUID().toString, login, email, password.sha256.hex))
      .map(authData => encodeToken(authData.id))
```

AuthDataStorage.scala

```
...
override def saveAuthData(authData: AuthData): Future[AuthData] =
    db.run((auth returning auth).insertOrUpdate(authData)).map(_ => authData)
...
```

Since I'm new to Scala and Slick, can anyway provide the information why this exception is occurring even though I've defined `O.AutoInc` in Model. I'm using MySQL RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `returning auth`. Instead of returning `auth` i.e complete object, Just return the auto-increment Id `id`. Slick does not support returning the complete object, though it compiles correctly. It does not generate a valid sql query.

Once you can get access to the auto-increment `id` then you can build the `AuthData` using the argument of the function.

Code:

```
(auth returning auth.map(_.id)).insertOrUpdate(authData)).map(id => authData.copy(id = id))
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is the result of a MySQL behavior. As the Slick [documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/queries.html#inserting) states:

> Many database systems only allow a single column to be returned which must be the table’s auto-incrementing primary key. If you ask for other columns a `SlickException` is thrown at runtime (unless the database actually supports it).

Change the `saveAuthData` method to return the `id` column on an upsert:

```
override def saveAuthData(authData: AuthData): Future[AuthData] =
  db.run((auth returning auth.map(_.id)).insertOrUpdate(authData))
    .map(idFromDb => authData.copy(id = idFromDb.getOrElse(authData.id)))
```

In the above code, `idFromDb` is a `Some[Int]` for an insert and a `None` for an update.

Comment: Can you please look into this forked repo:[akka-http-rest](https://github.com/itsursujit/akka-http-rest)